# filter datagirdview on input of two text box

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

this is what i am trying ...:

```
DataView dv = new DataView(table);
dv.RowFilter = String.Format("model like '%{0}%'", textBox2.Text);
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
{
   dv.RowFilter = String.Format("vendor like '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
}

purchase_mobile_DG.DataSource = dv;
```

where table is the datatable which have all the data from database ....i have two text box so what i want to do is that when i type in first text box it filter datagridview and after that when i write in second textbox it filters data from the filtered datagridview of first text box

Comment: So, where is the problem?

Comment: @Usman when i type some thing in first text-box it filters the data...but after it when i type some thing in second text box it starts from start ...what i want is that it should filtered data already filtered from first text box input

Comment: @user2137186 you should use previous filter with the new one as `dv.RowFilter=dv.RowFilter+ **(with AND operator)Your required filter**;`

Comment: um what can u edit my code?

Comment: because i am getting a syntax error

Comment: @user2137186 check my answer..what is Syntax Error?

Comment: @kostasch.when i type some thing in first text-box it filters the data...but after it when i type some thing in second text box it starts from start ...what i want is that it should filtered data already filtered from first text box input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use my edited code it as

```
DataView dv = new DataView(table);
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
{
   dv.RowFilter = String.Format("vendor like '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
}

dv.RowFilter = dv.RowFilter == "" ? String.Format("model like '%{0}%'", textBox2.Text) : dv.RowFilter + String.Format("AND model like '%{0}%'", textBox2.Text);

purchase_mobile_DG.DataSource = dv;
```

Comment: 2nd text box value is not filtering any thing

Comment: what i want is that when i write nokia in vendor it should list all nokia mobile in data grid view and when i write model like 3310 or e71 or lumia 920 it should filtered that nokia filtered record and only show me one record which is nokia lumia 920

Comment: @user2137186 `textbox1` is the textbox of `vendor` and the other one is `model`??OK?? and please use a convention while assigning control's name, this is a best practice

Comment: yeah and textbox2 is for model but when i write some thing in textbox 2 it is doing nothing ...and i have already edited your code by writing model instead of vendor and textbox2 instead of textbox1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var dv = new DataView(table);

dv.RowFilter = String.IsNullOrEmpty(vendorTextBox.Text)
             ? ""
             : String.Format("vendor like '%{0}%' and (model like '%{1}%' or '{1}' = '')", vendorTextBox.Text, modelTextBox.Text);

purchase_mobile_DG.DataSource = dv;
```

Also, please name your controls "vendorTextBox" and "modelTextBox"